# Facebook shop with woocommerce inventory

Tags: wordpress, facebook, woocommerce

I have a Wordpress Woocommerce site which I want to integrate to Facebook shop using this plugin https://woocommerce.com/products/facebook/.

No my question for someone using this plugin is,

- When someone buys from this Facebook shop, how do we receive the order and payment. Does this all happen on our Woocommerce website or Facebook shop and then Facebook shop send back the details to our Woocommerce site?
- How do we generate invoices, on Facebook shop or Woocommerce site?
- How often does this Facebook plugin syncs our products from Woocommerce to Facebook shop?

Comment: Sounds like questions that should be directed at the plugin developer ...

Comment: I did ask but I got generic reply saying visit the github page to report any issue.

Comment: Well then I suggest you go and do that. Chances that someone comes walking by here who happens to use that very same plugin are rather slim, I suppose.